# batch loop command with different variable values

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm looking for a way to exchange variable values (strings) in a batch-file while looping over a command.

varA has 4 different values and varB 18 different values

```
@echo off
set varA="foo"
set varB="bar"

echo %varA% and %varB%  (sample command)
pause
```

the goal is to loop the command 72-times (=4*18) with the different variable values. I can produce a list with all the combinations ready to use e.g.

```
varA="foo"
varB="bar"

varA="foo2"
varB="bar"
...
```

I'm guessing this is achievable in batch with a external config- or text-file, but I seem to be searching for the wrong things. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `FOR %%a IN ("a" "b" ...)`

Comment: I really zoned out there. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to nest a `For` loop inside another.

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "varA=1 2 3 4"
Set "varB=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18"
For %%A In (%varA%) Do For %%B In (%varB%) Do Echo %%A %%B (sample command)
Pause
```